# Unable to Click Date field. Error getting is "element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (208, 1353)"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have written below code to click on date field but unable to click and getting `element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (208, 1353)` error. Can someone please let me know what is wrong with the below code:

```
public class Exercise1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:/Users/tanrawat/Desktop/Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='form-field-travel_comp_date']")).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's not clicking is because the element isn't actually clickable. Make the script scroll down till the element is visible, then click it. I'm not a java programmer, here's my python script for that:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions")
date_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='form-field-travel_comp_date']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", date_element)
time.sleep(1)
date_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='form-field-travel_comp_date']")
date_element.click()
```

I've asked chatGPT to convert it to java, here's the result:

```java
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");
WebElement dateElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='form-field-travel_comp_date']"));

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", dateElement);

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

dateElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='form-field-travel_comp_date']"));
dateElement.click();
driver.quit();
```

So you make javascript scroll down till the element is in the browser viewport, then you make the script sleep for a bit (that's because `execute_script` is asynchronous, so the script will click even if `execute_script` didn't finish execution.)

Now assigning the same element to the date_element variable isn't always necessary, but sometimes it fixes the stale element issue. You can also make selenium scroll down instead of js, but sometimes I prefer doing stuff in js if selenium isn't working.

Comment: @tanuja rawat please let me know if anything isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

If selenium's `click()` method for any reason is not able to perform click on any web element, you can always use Selenium's `Action` class to perform the same.

Refer the code below with in-line explanation:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");
// Below line will click on Consent button of the pop-up
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Consent']")).click();
        
// below 3 lines of code will use Selenium's Action class to click on the desired element
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='form-field-travel_comp_date']"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

Import required for `Action` class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```